# Update a string from the front-end

Tags: forms, front-end

I want to have a form with a submit button, that every time the user clicks on submit, it updates a string (named `order_string`) and sends it to the back-end form to process. This is a part of my code in the single template (named `single-orders`). Orders is a CPT. I also want to use `functions.php` in this approach, but I don't know how.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        //alert("windows Loaded!!");
            var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
            var o_string = get_string();
            alert(o_string);
            for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
                checkboxes[i].onclick = function(){
                    o_string = get_string();
                    document.getElementsByName('o_string')[0].setAttribute('value', o_string);
                }
            }
        }
        function get_string(){
            var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
            //var o_string = '';
            var array = new Array();
            for(var j=0;j<checkboxes.length;j++){
                if (checkboxes[j].checked) array.push(checkboxes[j].value);
            }
            o_string = array.join('+');
            return o_string;
        }
</script>

<?php
$order_str = $_POST['o_string'];

update_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'order_str',$order_str);
var_dump($order_str);

$progress_str = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'progress_str',1);
$progress_arr = explode( '+', $progress_str );
$project_str = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'project_str',1);
$project_arr = explode( '+', $project_str );
$done_str = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'done_str',1);
$done_arr = explode( '+', $done_str );

$prg_set_arr = array();
$done_set_arr = array();
$prj_set_arr = array();

$order_str = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'order_str', 1 );
$order_arr = array();

$order_list = array('sitetypes','modules', 'features', 'attributes', 'standards');
$args = array('post_type' => $order_list , 'orderby' => 'menu_order' );
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

if (have_posts){
    the_post();
    ?>
    <li> Welcome user: <?php the_author(); ?> <li>
    <li><?php the_title();?></li>
    <li><?php the_content();?></li>
    <?php
}

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    if( !empty( $order_str ) ) $order_arr = explode( '+', $order_str );

    $order_sections = array();
    foreach( $order_list as $order_type){
        $order_sections[ $order_type ] = array();
    }
    $parents = array();
    global $post;
    while( $the_query->have_posts() ){
        $the_query->the_post();
        if( $post->post_parent ) $parents[] = $post->post_parent;
        $order_sections[ $post->post_type ][ $post->ID ] = $post->post_title;
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
    <ul><?php
    foreach( $order_sections as $key => $order_section ){
        $post_type = get_post_type_object( $key );
        if( $post_type ){?>
            <li class="section">
                <div class="section_title"><?php echo $post_type->label;?></div>
                    <ul><?php
                        foreach( $order_section as $choice_id => $choice_title ){
                            if( in_array( $choice_id, $parents ) ) continue; ?>
                            <li class="item">
                                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" 
                                name="post-<?php echo $choice_id;?>" 
                                value="<?php echo $choice_id;?>" <?php 
                                echo (in_array( $choice_id, $order_arr ) ? 'checked' : '');
                                echo (in_array( $choice_id, $progress_arr ) ? ' disabled' : ''); ?> />
                                <?php echo $choice_title;?>
                            </li><?php
                        }?>
                        </ul>
                    </li><?php
                }
            }?>
            </ul><?php 
        }
?>
<html>
    <body>
            <form action="" method="post">      
                <input type="box" name="o_string" value="<?php echo $order_str;?>"/>            
                <input type="submit" >
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cant read those codes, just i noticed, that you should filter the $_POST request(SECURITY issues),  before saving into database.

Comment: Don't reveal such a big part of your private code like this in public. always simplify your code blocks and remove uninformative parts. Also try to use meaningful tags and separate JavaScript from PHP from CSS